# Loading script dynamically works with remote link but not with downloaded code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load a script dynamically in React, it works, however only if I link it directly from GitHub like this:

```
  const createScript = () => {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://bernardo-castilho.github.io/DragDropTouch/DragDropTouch.js';
    script.onload = function () {
      setScriptLoadingState('LOADED');
      console.log('Script loaded');
    };
    script.onerror = function () {
      setScriptLoadingState('FAILED');
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };
```

I want to load it from a script located in my folders after I have downloaded it like such, but it doesn't work:

```
  const createScript = () => {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = './polyfill.js';
    script.onload = function () {
      setScriptLoadingState('LOADED');
      console.log('Script loaded');
    };
    script.onerror = function () {
      setScriptLoadingState('FAILED');
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I load it successfully from a local folder dynamically as well?

Here is my full code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  Scheduler,
  WeekView,
  MonthView,
} from '@progress/kendo-react-scheduler';

import { Grid, GridColumn } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';

import gridData from './data.js';

const App = () => {
  const MyScheduler = React.createRef();
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [dragItem, setDragItem] = React.useState('');
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [scriptLoadingState, setScriptLoadingState] = React.useState('IDLE');

  const createScript = () => {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = './polyfill.js';
    script.onload = function () {
      setScriptLoadingState('LOADED');
      console.log('Script loaded');
    };
    script.onerror = function () {
      setScriptLoadingState('FAILED');
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };

  const handleDropItem = (e) => {
    let start = e.target.getAttribute('data-slot-start');
    let end = e.target.getAttribute('data-slot-end');
    let startDate = new Date(parseInt(start));
    let endDate = new Date(parseInt(end));
    let newEvent = {
      id: dragItem.taskID,
      title: dragItem.title,
      StartTimezone: null,
      start: startDate,
      end: endDate,
    };
    setData([newEvent, ...data]);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    createScript();

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
    let schedulerElement = MyScheduler.current.element;
    schedulerElement.addEventListener('drop', handleDropItem);
    schedulerElement.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => e.preventDefault());

  });

  const GridRowRender = (tr, props) => {
    const trProps = {
      draggable: true,
      onDragStart: (e) => {
        setDragItem(props.dataItem);
      },
    };
    return React.cloneElement(tr, { ...trProps }, tr.props.children);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Scheduler
        data={data}
        defaultDate={new Date('2013/6/13')}
        ref={MyScheduler}
      >
        <WeekView showWorkHours={false} />
        <MonthView />
      </Scheduler>
      <hr />
      <Grid data={gridData} rowRender={GridRowRender}>
        <GridColumn field="taskID" />
        <GridColumn field="title" />
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

Comment: You can check the full URL by hitting F12 on your browser, and look at the network tab. You may need to refresh the page or trigger the event to load the file. Maybe it will indicate the wrong folder on your server ?

Comment: The status code is 200 and the path is correct, however, I am getting this error: Refused to execute script from 'https://react-y2rhjd-ovexud.stackblitz.io/polyfill.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. Tried setting a preload tag, but that didn't work